# How to redirect STDERR within script?

Tags: perl, stderr

I can redirect `STDERR` from the command line by doing:

```
perl myscript.pl 2> err.txt
```

How can I do this within the script so that the person running the script doesn't have to do it?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html - Search for the word "dup"

Comment: @Miller I want it not to go to the screen and only to the file

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do

```
open STDERR, '>', "$errfile"
    or warn "Cannot redirect STDERR to $errfile: $!";
```

If this is in a library, call `carp` instead of `warn`. That requires `use Carp;`, for core module [Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html).

In case the `STDERR` stream will need to be restored first save it, as shown in [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).